# Width of select list of a DropDownList in MVC too big because of very long string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, word-wrap

This is the code in Razor:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SurveyTitle", ViewBag.SurveyTitle as SelectList, new { style = "max-width: 300px;" })
```

The problem is, this way I can only change the width of the dropdown, but not inside it after I click on it and it lists all the options.
I'm am listing some very long strings from a DB and the list after I press the dropdown goes to the right and outside of the screen.

How can I shorten it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Selects are among a handful of elements that are actually OS-controls, not browser-controls. What that means is that the browser delegates the rendering to the OS and as a result, only has limited control of how they look and function. One of those things that's outside of the browser's control is the width of the expanded dropdown.

What you might be able to do is to use a JavaScript library that generates custom select-like controls. I personally like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/). The "control" is generated from regular HTML elements like `div`s, and as a result, is completely 100% customizable end to end. Without using something like this, there's nothing you can do.